# Drawn 2D shape into numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, code-generation, shapes

I am working on a project which involves the use of bounding boxes (anything from a triangle to n-sided polygon). The bounding boxes are defined in `numpy` arrays of x, y, z tuples.

At the moment, to create a new shape, I use what I consider are inefficient methods, that involve multiple steps most of which are manual point picking. Needless to say, this is very time consuming.

I was wondering if there is an easier way of doing this - an interactive tool which let's you pick points in a 2D / 3D space and outputs an array of Cartesian coordinates (e.g. `array = numpy.array([(1, 2, 1), (2, 3, 1), (5, 5, 0)])`? Even a parametric polygon generator would be extremely useful. If any of you is aware of a similar tool or has any reference to one, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Look for "convex hull scipy numpy"

Comment: @Joe, I have been using that, I want the opposite of it :)

Comment: If you want to pick manually, any GUI toolkit can return the position of a click-event that you can transform. https://matplotlib.org/users/event_handling.html or http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/auto/example_select_red_balls.html